# jQuery mobile popup dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

My jQuery mobile popup header doesn't have the same size as the content.

[image]

jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery mobile 1.2.0.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="commentPopup" style="width: 800px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Please enter your comment</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="okComment" data-theme="a">OK</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">CANCEL</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For info, I open it with `$('#commentPopup').popup("open");`.

Is it possible to disable the scroll while the popup is opened?
Is it possible to prevent the user from closing the popup when clicking in another place of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Are you overriding jQM classes somewhere? `.ui-header` or so? to prevent closing popup, add `data-dismissible="false"` to the popup div. http://jsbin.com/ulavul/1/

Comment: Yes you were right. I was overriding a `.ui-content`. It's solved. Concerning the `dismissible`, I think it's only available since jQM 1.3.0. However I use jQM 1.2.0. Is there any equivalent or trick I could use? Thanks

Comment: I recommend using jQM 1.3.0.

Comment: Well if I change, I have to re-validate the whole application... Cost time!

Comment: I guess dismissible is also available in 1.2.0

Comment: Not in [here jQM 1.2.0](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/options.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overriding a CSS `.ui-content` class as @Omar found it.

The problem is solved.

Concerning the dismissible, this is not possible with jQM version < 1.3.0.